Streamlit AG Grid table changing column width on st.tabs
I am building an app in Streamlit using AG Grid to display data.
I need to be able to add multiple tabs, each showing specific data in exactly the same table, it's just filtered based on the subject.
All my column widths are fixed, so this shouldn't change, but when I add more than one tab, then the first few columns width are set to 0, and the table gets unreadable.
I'm not using Fit_contents as the auto size mode.
What am I missing?
if not selected_subject_codes:
    st.write("Please select a subject to view the overview.")
    st.stop()
else:
    tabs = st.tabs(subject_names)
    for tab, subject_code, subject_name in zip(tabs, selected_subject_codes, subject_names):
        with tab:
            # Filter the DataFrame for the selected subject
            selected_subject_df = subject_expenses_df[
                subject_expenses_df['subject_code'] == subject_code
            ][selected_columns].sort_values(by='sort_order', ascending=False)

            # Get grid options
            subject_overview_grid_options = get_grid_options('subject_overview_categories', selected_subject_df, recent_period=recent_period_month)

            # Display the grid
            AgGrid(
                selected_vessel_df,
                custom_css=custom_css,
                gridOptions=subject_overview_grid_options,
                allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
                alwaysShowHorizontalScroll=True,
                height=850,
                theme='balham'  # Options: alpine, balham, material, streamlit
            )


I'm currently getting exactly same problems
